# Counting number of frequency of all letters

Tags: python

I try to count the number of frequency of each letters

Here is my main file:

```
from moduleA import get_text, process_data,print_output
import os

filename1 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'script01.txt') 
filename2 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'script02.txt') 
myList1 = get_text(filename1)
myList2 = get_text(filename2)


data01=process_data(myList1)
data02=process_data(myList2)


print_output(data01)
print_output(data02)
```

Here is the moduleA file:

```
def get_text(file_name):
text = None
try:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        text = f.read()
except IOError as io:
    print(str(io))
return text

def process_data(text_data):
from string import ascii_lowercase
data = {}
for char in text_data:
    ch = char.lower()
    if ch in ascii_lowercase:
        if ch not in data:
            data[ch] = 1
        else:
            data[ch] += 1  
return(data)

def print_output(data):
     for char in sorted(data.items()):
     print(str(char), str(data[char]))
```

This is the error I got：

```
 print(str(char), str(data[char]))
 KeyError: ('a', 867)
```

I have no idea why I am not getting the whole dictionary but only the first line

Answer (score 2):

yes, or you could use `collections Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

frequencies = Counter(text)
```

for the printing, you must iterate over keys in sorted order:

```
def print_output(frequencies):
     for key in sorted(frequencies.keys()):
         print(key, frequencies[key])
```

Answer (score 2):

You build the dictionary like this

```
    if ch in ascii_lowercase:
        if ch not in data:
            data[ch] = 1
        else:
            data[ch] += 1
```

So I imagine the keys are characters and the values are the counts of the characters:

```
{'a':867, 'b':233, ....}
```

[`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) produces (key, value) pairs as tuples - like `('a', 867)`.

```
def print_output(data):
    for char in sorted(data.items()):
        #print(char)
        print(str(char), str(data[char]))
```

So `char` *in* `for char in sorted(data.items()):` is ('a', 867) and you are trying to use it as a key with `str(data[char])` which causes a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError).

Try

```
def print_output(data):
     for char, count in sorted(data.items()):
         print(str(char), str(count))
```

or

```
def print_output(data):
     for char in sorted(data):
         print(str(char), str(data[char]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!